# What software allows you to make an image of your boot partition (OS) in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, images, acronis-trueimage

I have been using Acronis True Image to make an image of my boot partition so i can restore it whenever my system gets laggy or if anything goes wrong. But ever since I have installed Windows 7 I haven't been able to do so sucessfully and have always been using the Windows repair utility to repair the installation.

Windows 7 has the boot parition and the system reserved parition, so do I have to make an image of both the drives ?

I'm sure some users here would have made an image of their boot drive/partition so please suggest how do i accomplish the same.

Comment: I am curious how restoring your boot partition would make your system less laggy? If that works I would be surprised.

Comment: @MrStatic - I'm assuming he's referring to the mythical "OS Bloat" which is really just people installed a bunch of crap that runs in the background that they forget to uninstall. Usually this occurs in tandem with some malware to give the illusion that systems magically slow down over time for no reason

Comment: @mrStatic: I'd assume he's restoring his system back to a clean state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this ‘reserve partition’ you are talking about is the boot one – it should be restored as well. There are some cases, for example this ‘reserve partition’ is very first one and system is the next one – restoring only system partition will change partition structure and repair will be required.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I understand, your Windows 7 requires the repair each time you're restoring ti using Acronis True Image Home 2010, is that correct?

If yes,  I'd recommend you to download the version which is based on another loader (the version has some extended list of drivers and startup parameters). We have implemented the possibility to download the appropriate ISO file after logging into your account (the serial number should be registered). This option is available for the current and (n-1) versions. Please log in to your account, go to the Registered products and downloads section -> Bootable media. Download the file.
To get access to the ISO you should first register Acronis software.

Comment: To whoever is running the Acronis account, please note that introductions and salutations are frowned upon here. Just get to the answer. You will get downvoted into oblivion and no one will see your answer if it looks like you are posting a form letter as an answer. (I'm not the downvoter since this is a valid answer, but I'm also not going to upvote it since it is a canned response copied and pasted into the answer box)

Comment: Thanks for your remark. We are new to Superuser, but definitely will do our best to help users with any Acronis related issues.

Comment: How do you clone a partition with acronis? I can only select disks, not partition.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to purchase third party software to do this. [Windows backup](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/backup-and-restore) natively performs an image based backup of your system disk on Windows 7.